# Remote rails form (simple_form_for)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

**How to make a 'create' action call only js.erb file and not reload page finding a missing template?**

I'm trying to create a book object with remote form, but the action 'create' results in such error:

`Missing template books/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :axlsx, :haml, :rabl]}.`

books/_form.haml (library: @library):

```
= simple_form_for @book, url: library_books_path(library), remote: true do |f|
```

books_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @books = @library.books
  @book = Book.new
end

def create
  @book = @library.books.create(book_params)
end

def destroy
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @book.destroy
end
```

books/create.js.erb:

```
$('#books_table').replaceWith('<%= j render "table", books: @books %>');
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed books/create.js.erb:

```
<% if !@book.valid? %>
  alert("error!")
<% else %>
  $('#books_table').replaceWith('<%= j render "table", books: @books %>');
<% end %>
```

In this case, when `@book` is not valid, js file is called fine, but in case it can be saved - there's still error about missing template

Answer (score 1):

The `remote: true` option is not being picked up, because you can see `:formats=>[:html]` in your error message, NOT `:formats=>[:js]` as expected.

Are you sure you have **jquery_ujs** set up properly in your asset pipeline? This is what picks up the `remote: true` option, and causes the form to submit via JS rather than the default HTML format.

Check your `/app/assets/javascript/application.js` file

You need to have:

`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs`

in your Sprockets manifest.

Comment: Both items (jquery &  jquery_ujs) are already included in application.js